# Perl Apache : Perl script displayed as plain text

Tags: perl, apache, windows-7, configuration, cgi

While configuring with `apache` and `perl cgi scripts`, don't know why `index.cgi`/`index.pl` are displayed as plain text instead of executing them.
When I put `http://localhost` in browser it displays below code, instead of executing it.

```
List item
    #!C:/Dwimperl/perl/bin/perl.exe -w

     print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
        print <<HTML;
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>A perl web page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h3>A hello world form perl</h3>
        </body>

        HTML
        exit;
```

This are parts of `httpd.conf` file which I have edited most of the times (after reading various online reference, tutorials)

```
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
<Directory "D:\webserver">

Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so

# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.cgi index.pl

AccessFileName .htaccess

# To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
# (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
#
#AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/Apache/Apache2/cgi-bin/"
```

Comment: it's ok to downvote, but if you know the answer, please let me know. I had hard time configuring httpd.conf file.

Comment: Is your Perl properly installed. Apache generally prints file contents if it's not finding perl specified by your script. http configuration is a headache. I agree.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When browser is printing code of script that means it's unable to find the application to run the script. Below two lines should be your first steps to solve this. AddHandler will make sure files ending with `.cgi` and `.pl` to be treated as cgi scripts. And `+ExecCGI` option will allow to execute the script. Also make sure your script is pointing to correct perl binary location.

> ```
>     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
>     Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
> ```

Also There are some mistakes/misconfiguration points in your httpd.conf

- Alias line should point to **cgi-bin** directory where your cgi scripts are present.

> ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "D:\webserver\cgi-bin"

- For same cgi-bin directory following configuration should be in `httpd.conf`. You should replace your `<Directory "D:\webserver">` part with below.

> ```
> <Directory "D:\webserver\cgi-bin" />
>     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
>     Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
>     AllowOverride None  
> </Directory>
> ```

- Try running your cgi script from command line like below. It should print or run from command line first.

> perl test.cgi

- Make sure you have read-write recursive permissions to `cgi-bin` directory and your cgi script. And also you can create directory or file with write permissions. If not create a `cgi-bin` directory at some other place where you can have write permissions and provide rather its path in `alias` and `directory` attributes in `httpd.conf` instead.
- Check apache error log for exact error message every time you run into apache conf issues. It will give you good insight into the problem.

Also [this link](http://homepages.paradise.net.nz/milhous/cgi.htm) should help you.

(*Extra comment, not by the original answerer*: You may also need to enable the `cgi` module. For me, the final step to getting cgi to work on a fresh install of Apache 2 was `sudo a2enmod cgi`. Before I did that, the website simply showed me the contents of the script.)

> `sudo a2enmod cgi`

Comment: thank you very much. Your given link makes httpd.conf file configuration easy and understandable. I deleted old httpd.conf (heavily edited), made new httpd.conf file from httpd-default file. Edited newly made httpd.conf file as guided in http://homepages.paradise.net.nz/milhous/cgi.htm and changed CGI script, and it worked. Again, thanks for helping out, because above link, not only solves this problems, but provides info about post, get, database etc.

Comment: `sudo a2enmod cgi` did the trick for me, using a Raspberry Pi, if it matters.

Comment: Thanks for the extra comment... for me, `a2enmod cgi` was required.

Answer (score 2):

The directory/location/file doesn't have the right handler associated with it, or doesn't have the `ExecCGI` option enabled. See [Apache Tutorial: Dynamic Content with CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html).

Answer (score 2):

change new version of apache :
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

Answer (score 1):

on mac os x 10.8

i had to do this

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

and

uncomment this

```
#AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

Comment: on 10.10 Yosemite I also needed to do `LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so` and then `sudo apachectl restart`. For my Options declaration, I had to do: `Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI` due to some complaining about only using one + sign...

Answer (score 1):

```
 # use types www.site.com/visible-in-url
 # Apache serves /var/path/to/dir
 ScriptAlias /visible-in-url/ /var/path/to/dir/

 # Note the order of the aliases matters - first cgi than static content
 # Note this dir is a symlink pointing to the desirable directory
 <Directory "/var/path/to/dir">
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    AllowOverride Indexes
    Options +ExecCGI +MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
 </Directory>

 <Files ~ "\.(pl|cgi)$">
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::PerlRun
    Options +ExecCGI +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    PerlSendHeader On
 </Files>
```

Comment: The <Files > section fixed the issue in the new Apache 2.4.  I feel they took the old school Microsoft route, and broke just about everything with that update.  Sure, it's better, more secure, good direction.  But wow, what a disaster.

Answer (score 1):

> When browser is printing code of script that means it's unable to find
>   the application to run the script.

With `Apache 2.4` (on OSX Yosemite, 10.10.5), if I use a shebang line with the wrong path, my browser displays:

> **Internal Server Error**

But even with a valid shebang line, I could not get my cgi program to execute by following the advice in the accepted answer--Apache just served up the text of the program to my browser.  After some experimenting, I found that the only change I needed to make to my `/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` file was uncommenting the line:

```
LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
```

My cgi programs have the extensions .pl, .py, and .rb depending on what language I'm programming in (and the apache cgi-bin directory contains a test cgi script with no extension), and they all execute without having to specify valid extensions anywhere in the httpd.conf file.  My default `httpd.conf` file has only the following relevant lines:

```
<IfModule alias_module>
    #Lots of comments here

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>
...
...
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The shebang line that I'm using is, depending on what language my cgi program is written in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

or:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

A cgi program has to be an executable file as well, or else you will get an **Internal Server** error:

```
$ chmod a+x myprog.pl
```

`a+x` => all + executable. In other words, add the executable permission to each of owner, group, other.

And, at a minimum the cgi program has to generate a `Content-Type header` before outputting the body of the response:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
print "<h1>Hello, World.</h1>";
```

(By the way, that exact code will work in perl, python, or ruby.) Otherwise, once again you will get an **Internal Server** error.

The url to execute the cgi script:

```
http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/myprog.pl
```

This is how I installed apache:

```
~/Downloads$ tar xvfz httpd-2.4.18.tar.bz2
...
...
~/Downloads$ cd httpd-2.4.18
...
...
~/Downloads/httpd-2.4.18$ ./configure --help
...
...
--enable-so       DSO capability. This module will be automatically
                  enabled unless you build all modules statically.
...
...
```

I had no idea what the heck that meant, but the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) say to install apache with that option, so I went ahead and did this:

```
~/Downloads/httpd-2.4.18$ ./configure --enable-so
...
...
~/Downloads/httpd-2.4.18$ make
...
...
~/Downloads/httpd-2.4.18$ sudo make install
```

Apache DSO docs [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/dso.html).

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else has worked, be sure that you're displaying the HTML page that calls your executable script from the local server, e.g. http://192.168.0.15/yourPage.html. If you call it by opening the HTML page in your browser as a file, it will always display your executable script as a file.