# Perl cgi scripts ran as plain text

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

Before we begin, I want to say that I have read this: [Perl Apache : Perl script displayed as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792978/perl-apache-perl-script-displayed-as-plain-text)

I've read it, tried the things, didn't work out (Sadly)

I am on Ubuntu

I want to run cgi scripts, they compile fine, I have the appropriate rights to the folder (atleast I don't get an error that I don't when I try to enter it through the browser)and the files run as plain text.

First the file which I am trying to run:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use CGI qw/:standard/;
 print header,
 h1('CGI.pm is simple.'),
 end_html;
```

And I get as output the source code.

The path to the folder is `/var/www/a2/`

and the configuration in the apache .config file is:

```
ScriptAlias /a2/ /var/www/a2/
<Directory "/var/www/a2">
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
AllowOverride None
Options ExecCGI
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The file compiles fine and prints the html in the terminal.

My only guess is that I have not given proper rights to the file.

EDIT: I checked the error log. It doesn't give an error for this.

EDIT: After a very long discussion with Mark Setchell the error was discovered. I had posted this in the wrong .config file and I had been using the wrong (unconfigured folder) all along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things to try:

1. Ensure your script is named with the extension ".pl"
2. Ensure your script is executable. Do this by typing:

   chmod +x   yourscript.pl
3. As Mark says, ensure you have the shebang as the very first line of your script:

   #!/usr/bin/perl
4. Remove the "1;" at the end, you only need that for packages/modules.

Comment: 1) The script has extention .pl. 2) I executed the command as root. 3) I have the shebang. 4) I have updated the script with a new example I am using (shorter and more straightforward). It is still printed as plain text.

Comment: So, if the script is called "fred.pl", what happens when you type "./fred.pl"

Comment: Okay! We are making progress. I do not have permission to run the script. It says "permission denied". The script is tt1.pl, the command which I ran was sudo chmod -x tt1.pl and I got no error.

Comment: Just for a minute, try typing "chmod 777 tt1.pl", then try again.

Comment: It still doesn't work and now it gives an error when I try to run it ( ./tt1.pl)

Comment: Check your perl interpreter is really at /usr/bin/perl, by typing "which perl" or "whereis perl" and see if it matches the first line of your script - edit script if not. If that doesn't work, tell me what error you get when trying to run it.

Comment: Basically the first path is: "/usr/bin/perl/ so the path must be ok. Now it get's wierd. When just compiling I get that the syntax is ok, however when I try to run it I get  line 3: use: command not found
Warning: unknown mime-type for "header," -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "header,"
./tt1.pl: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `'CGI.pm is simple.''
./tt1.pl: line 5: ` h1('CGI.pm is simple.'),' EDIT: Maybe a package is missing?

Comment: change the commas at the ends of the lines to semi-colons.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43106/discussion-between-mark-setchell-and-bloodcount)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

at the top of your script.  Without it, the CGI handler won't know how to execute it.

Comment: A funny error came up! Now it is trying to download it :D Edit: Download as in the browser is asking me where to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure apache cgi mode is enable

```
sudo a2enmod cgi   //will enable the cgi mode
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Make sure that the file permission to the .cgi file is okay

```
sudo chmod 755 yourFile.cgi
```

Try executing it through terminal

```
perl /Path_To_The_File/fileName.cgi
```

Ensure that your fileName.cgi contains bellow code at top of the file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
```